# How does R recognize which column is the unique identifier in my dataset?

Tags: r, primary-key, stata, pca, identifier

I am fairly new to R and having trouble with my unique identifiers of participants. 
I imported my dataset from Stata into R, all good. All variables appear as they should including my ID variable. However, I am trying to run PCA but weirdly the PCA is using my ID variable as an item variable. Does anyone know what the problem might be? The ID variable is currently `chr`. I thought R automatically recognized unique IDs for participants?

Comment: Welcome, it would be very helpful if you could share at least a snippet of your data and what pca function you are using `prcomp` ??? Odds are you just need to tell the function not to include ID in your analysis but exactly how depends on your data and what command you're using.

Comment: Please show your code implementation with [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451). We need to see how you are *trying to run PCA*. R is an extendable language and may have several PCA solutions. Include all `library` lines.

Answer (score 0):

R does not really have a concept of a unique identifier like an SQL primary key. Instead, you have a few options. You can exclude the identifier from the data you feed into PCA like this:

```
df_for_pca = df[, 2:ncol(df)] # assuming id is the first column of df
```

you can also add row names which are not treated as data by most functions but still retained for when you need them:

```
rownames(df) = df[, 1] # assuming id is the first column of df
df[, 1] = NULL
```

EDIT: a solution from comments using packages `textshape` and `tibble`:

```
# assuming the id column is called 'my_id'
df_for_pca = df %>% remove_rownames() %>% column_to_rownames(var = 'my_id')
```

Comment: Hello everyone! Thank you so much for being so quick in responding. I tried the following code using 'tidyverse' and it worked!

 example1 <- hfitrial1 %>%
  remove_rownames() %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = 'ptid')